# PHP outputting html tags

Tags: php, html, nginx

I have a very old PHP application, that actually runs on php 5.3 using Apache on a Debian 6 machine (I know, I know).

Last week I migrated it to a Debian 9 machine running NGINX and php 5.6, but now I got a very strange issue.

One of the scripts do some checks on a database and then output "1" or "0" - just that. This script is requested via ajax.

For some reason, instead of outputting just "0" or "1", sometimes it outputs a full html page, with doctype and head, title and body tags, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
1
</body>
</html>
```

To do some testing, I created an empty file with just a "1" on it, and the issue happens on this file too:

```
echo 1 > empty.php
```

This is driving me crazy. I don't know if it is a PHP issue, or NGINX. And the weird part is that the issue happens ***sometimes***, not always. But when it happens, the customers can't log in the application, so it is very annoying.

For now, i changed the javascript code that make the ajax request to strip out the html, but I would like to know why this happens.

Comment: Ensure your content type is the correct one `text/html`, is for, well html. So make sure this one page have the proper `text/plain` content type.

Comment: Still no luck. I changed the test file to this, but sometimes it outputs the full html, sometimes just the number 1:

`<?php header('Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8');?>
1`

Comment: Verify your other header then, specifically `cache-control` to see if this is not a cache issue (which seems it is given the random pattern you describe)